# Resolving 'File in Use' Error During IIS Deployment in Azure DevOps

Tags: iis, azure-devops, file-in-use

When I attempt to deploy to IIS, I consistently encounter a 'file in use' error.
I've tried using IIS Manage and Deploy tasks, Copy Files tasks, as well as deleting the 'web.config' file before deployment, but I still face the same issue after some time.

Is there a script or method I can utilize to copy files or deploy to IIS without encountering this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following ways to resolve this issue:

1. Directly restart the app pool (the target deployment machine). This will kill the process which is using the affected file.
2. Enable **Application Offline** for your app.

   - You can reference the docs "[**Taking Web Applications Offline with Web Deploy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/taking-web-applications-offline-with-web-deploy)" to configure the publish settings of your app.
   - If you use the [**IIS web app deploy task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/iisweb-app-deployment-on-machine-group-v0?view=azure-pipelines) in Azure Pipelines to deploy your app. This task has provided an option (**Take App Offline**) to enable **Application Offline**.
     [image]
     [image]

Comment: I have no detailed information related application pool using . & also don't have access to that server , 
I have already tried Take App Offline option . but error still occur after some time

Comment: @TahamiRizwan, Have you tried the steps on the docs "[Taking Web Applications Offline with Web Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/taking-web-applications-offline-with-web-deploy)"?

Comment: yes tried that also ..  but no success

Comment: @TahamiRizwan, How about manually create/copy an **`App_offline.htm`** file with any HTML content into the root directory of your app?

Comment: it displayed the page with that content  but when sometimes again give error locked by external process

Comment: @TahamiRizwan, Maybe, you need to try re-starting the app pool machine. You can open the pipeline definition to check the name of environment (for YAML pipeline) or deployment group (for classic release pipeline) used by the deploy job. Then on the left navigation bar, you can go to **`Pipelines`** > **`Environments`** (or **`Deployment groups`**), find and open the instance used by the deploy job. You can get the details of the app pool machine. Try to contact the admin of the machine to help to re-start the machine.